# KendoSplitter/Angular: How to set splitter height programmatically

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[In his plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rlSD7eMfJvHneUTxIHoD?p=preview) if you click the button, the KendoSplitter wrapper height is increased to 1000px and the splitter `resize` event is triggered, however the splitter is not redrawn. After clicking the buton, try to resize the horizontal divider and you'll see that the height actually changed. Any ideas how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="setHeight()">Increment Content2 Height</button>

<div id="div1" kendo-splitter="splitter1" 
         k-panes="[{collapsible: true, size: '120px'},{collapsible: true }]" 
         k-orientation="'horizontal'">

     <div kendo-splitter="splitter2"  
          k-panes="[{collapsible: true, size: '100px'},{collapsible: true}]" 
          k-orientation="'vertical'">
         <div>
             Content 11
         </div>
         <div>
             Content 12
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         Content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  $scope.setHeight = function() {
        $scope.splitter1.wrapper.height(1000);
        $scope.splitter1.trigger("resize");
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.splitter1.trigger("resize");` is not supported anymore.
Instead use: `kendo.resize($($scope.splitter1.wrapper[0]));`